# TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I get this error while building a music bot for my discord server. Tryin' to do a skip command but unfortunately can't figure out this error

```
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}skip`)) {
      if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Ni kanale tuuu');
      if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('Niera daugiau daaainuuu');
      serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.destroy();
      return undefined;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}stop`)) {
      if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Ni kanale tuuu');
      if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('Niera daugiau daaainuuu');
      serverQueue.songs = [];
      serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.destroy();
      return undefined;
  }
```

Tried googling, but haven't found a fix. Help

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use instead of `dispatcher.destroy()` is `dispatcher.end()`.

Comment: It was end at first, but I changed it to destroy. However it's the same error TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of null